# Past tense multiple times used

Tags: tense

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? It sounds a bit strange to me...

'In Narnia there was a prophecy which said that, when the four thrones at Cair Paravel were occupied by 'Sons or Daughters of Adam and Eve', not only the Witch's reign, but also her life would end.'

Answer (score 0):

> Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

Yes.

The entire narration is set in the past.

To analyze further, it begins by saying "In Narnia there **was** a prophecy". This implies the prophecy is no longer valid. If the prophecy were still open to coming true, even today, it could say "In Narnia there **has been** a well known prophecy, dating back hundreds of years".  The present perfect "has been" still connects to the present.  However, "was" is entirely in the past.  Proceeding from there, the remainder of the story about the prophecy is also set in the past, implying the events have completed.

In general, there are different alternatives.

1. An author may use the "historical present". That means, at some points in the story, switch to the present tense.

> In English grammar, the "historical present" is the use of a verb phrase in the present tense to refer to an event that took place in the past. - [thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/historical-present-verb-tense-1690928)

2. Quotes. If the prophecy were placed in quotations, repeating the words verbatim, present and future tenses could be applied: "It shall come to pass...."

However, those techniques of using the present tense to refer to the past tense are optional. They aren't required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, you mean the following sentence is also correct? 'In Narnia there was a prophecy which said that, when the four thrones at Cair Paravel are occupied by 'Sons or Daughters of Adam and Eve', not only the Witch's reign, but also her life will end.'

Comment: Or do I have to replace 'will end' by 'ends'?

Comment: Hmm. Such a (very) direct application of "historical present", switching mid-sentence, seems somehow problematic here. Quotes are better:  In Narnia there was a prophecy which declared: "When the four thrones at Cair Paravel are occupied by 'Sons or Daughters of Adam and Eve', the Witch's reign will end."   However, the author's usage of past tense is the best choice for this particular story. I'm not recommending the present tense.